# Why can't I add the newtonsoft.Json.dll ref to my project?

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio-2010, reference, json.net

I am trying to add a reference 'Newtonsoft.Json.dll' I have followed what he has asked. which adds this ref from 'browse' tab to 'recent' tab. If I look at the list of refs from the ref list it is listed but with a yellow flag.

When I hold the cursor over the flag it says: not available as it does not exist, or is not built?? So I have removed it from the list of ref's and try to re-add it.

It only appears in the 'recent' section and when I add it, I get:

A reference to 'Newtonsoft.Json.dll' could not be added.

Comment: Probably its not in the same location it was added from. Find where the dll file is then add it using "Browse". I would suggest putting it in a location that will not change

Comment: Check the target framework of your project and see if it is a match with the Newtonsoft dll target version.

Comment: why don't you try NuGet package manager to install [`Newtonsoft.Json`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/NewtonSoft.Json/)

Comment: im trying to re-add it here but cant find it ive searched the entire project with WE

Comment: @Damith i've used NuGet package to install it(thanks for the link), but it has installed it into my Orchard.Web project (which is where we originally have to browse for it-from the tutorial). So iv added a ref to my cars project, and browsed to the orchard.web/bin but it doesnt appear?

Comment: @John you can add package to any project by right click on project and select NuGet package manger and then install it

Comment: @Damith ahh i see....well closing and opening VS found the project so I was able to add it through browse...thanks for the help

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Its *probably* something in your build system: the dll is likely getting cleaned (as in deleted by a rebuild), or is in a directory that isn't under your solution, or simply isn't getting copied to the output directory.

I'm sorry I don't have a more specific piece of advice. What I'm going to do though is suggest you use a shot-gun to kill a mosquito: use [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/). In C# with Visual Studio (or any other .net IDE), you really want to use the nuget package manager, since it works so well.

1. Install the visual studio extension,
2. right click on your solution (dont do the project, do the solution)
3. select 'Manage Nuget Packages for Solution'
4. click 'online', in the search box type 'newtonsoft'
5. click 'Install' on 'Json.NET' (probably, what your looking for might be in another package, I'll ask you to track it down).

This will put it in a library directory, include it in the build path, and allow you to use the Intelli sense to auto-add the appropriate reference from your project.

Comment: Thanks. After reading your comment (and others) I eventually got my issue here resolved. In my case using the "Tools > Nuget Package Manager > Manage Nuget Package for Solution" led me to see there were many updates to my Nuget packages and after installing them I was back in business.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that the your project target framework is set to the correct version.  It might be that your target .NET framework for the project is lower than what the Newtonsoft dll was built under.  Right click on your project and see what it's set at.  You'll need to go view the properties.

Comment: target is .net framework 4. how do i know what version the dll is running under?

Comment: You can use a tool like ILDASM http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1%28VS.80%29.aspx or just read the docs of where you downloaded it from.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

Nuget works, but for older Visual Studios, such as 2005/2008, it can be tricky (And that, unfortunately, was my case).

I downloaded Json.NET [here](https://json.codeplex.com/releases/view/126052). Inside binaries, choose the one that matches your .Net Framework version, add the dll inside a folder of your project (e.g. lib), and include it as a reference. Then, have fun!

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is a stupid answer, but sometimes you make stupid mistakes ...: if you have several sub-projects in your solution, make sure you add the reference to the right one (or to all) !

Comment: Well, open the (sub) project, right-click on 'References' and choose 'add a reference'. Repeat for all projects concerned.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the Json.net is already install in your project.

If it is already installed go and remove the "package" entry from "packages.config" file. Now go to NuGet "Package Manager Console" and install the new package using the following command:

PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json {Your Project Name} 6.0.3 nuget.org

If it is not installed, goto NuGet and search for JSon.Net and select the project and click install.

[Sreekanth](https://twitter.com/_sreekanth_)

Answer (score 0):

In my case i was face the same problem then i am able to resolve by flowing the article

http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2011/05/referencing-custom-assembly-inside.html

Add the assembly to GAC
Before we can use our assembly, we have to add it to the global assembly cache (GAC). Open the Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt again (for Vista/Windows7/etc. open it as Administrator). And execute the following command.
gacutil /i d:\myMethodsForSSIS\myMethodsForSSIS\bin\Release\myMethodsForSSIS.dll